# Unable to return to login page after session expires in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, session, action-filter

I have created filter to check session and if it is expired i am redirecting to login page. This is my below code.

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
            {
            HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
           if(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name=="")
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Login/Index");
                return;
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
```

I decorated my action method as below.

```
 [SessionTimeOut]
  public PartialViewResult GetGridData(string client_id, string emp_id, string empciti_id, string Message)
```

It works fine. After session expires it will render login page. But problem i am facing is my layout page still appeares in top. In center my login page appears.[image: My login page appears in center. I have attached image.] so how can i fix this issue? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have created filter to check session and if it is expired i am redirecting to login page. This is my below code.

You're doing it bad. This is not the the good practice.

You already have an filter attribute called `AuthorizeAttribute`. I recommend to use it. And also check this [link](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity) which talk about **ASP.Net Identity** the easy way to implement authorization/authentication in your application.

Comment: i removed filter i created. i added AuthorizeAttribute and it works fine but login page appears in middle only as before

Comment: What do you mean by "middle only" ?

Comment: I have added image. Layout page also appears in top. Below to that login page appears.

Comment: I still gon"t get it. You need only the login page to be visible and nothing else? If so then make sure Login/Index action return a view and make sure that the layout page doesn't include anything else that require authentication.

Answer (score -1):

In your ~/Views/Login/Index.cshtml set -

```
Layout = null;
```